# how can a append a link into table column with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make it so i append a link at the end of each row, but it says "Click Here", and then it openes a link? Ill show you my code below but i dont know really how to work this out, iv been thinking for 2 hours now and came up with nothing...

```
 var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
 var childData = childSnapshot.val();

 var row = tblUsers.insertRow(rowIndex);
 var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
 var cellMovieName = row.insertCell(1);
 var cellPrice = row.insertCell(2);
 var cellLink = row.insertCell(3);

 cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childKey));
 cellMovieName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Title));
 cellPrice.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Price));
 cellLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode("CLICK ME" with the href attribute of childData.Title));

 rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-link-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out... with a little bit of both of your guys's knowlage you have provided, i made a solution to this check below:

```
 var text = document.createTextNode("This is link"); 
 var link = document.createElement('a');
 link.setAttribute('href', "https://google.com");
 link.setAttribute('html', "test");
 link.setAttribute('target', "_blank");
 link.appendChild(text);
 cellLink.appendChild(link);

 rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
```

So I Made The Text, Added It To The Column And Then Added The Attributes I Appreciate Everyone Helping Me!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do like this
You can't append child like that you need to do like

var list = document.getElementById("idhere");

var button = document.createElement('button');

button.value = "Click Me";
list.appendChild(button);

Now you can add attributes

var attribute = document.createAttribute("id"); // Can be class data-id whaterver you want onclick, anything you want
    attribute.value = "time"; // can be anything

button.setAttributeNode(attribute);

// Some Examples

```
    var span2 = document.createElement('span');

    span2.innerText = snapshot.val().message;

    var span_2_ID = document.createAttribute("id");
    span_2_ID.value = "post";

    // Time

    var span3 = document.createElement('span');

    span3.innerText = snapshot.val().time;

    var span_3_ID = document.createAttribute("id");
    span_3_ID.value = "time";


    span1.setAttributeNode(span_1_ID);
    span2.setAttributeNode(span_2_ID);
    span3.setAttributeNode(span_3_ID);

    var break1 = document.createElement('br');
    var break2 = document.createElement('br');
```

I hope this helps you